# Why can't build the docker image?

Tags: docker

I want to create a docker image according to the tutorial.[create docker image](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Docker-WeChat/)

1.vim `wechat.Dockerfile` ,paste all lines into the file.

```
ls -al wechat.Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian debian 1217 Apr 29 10:21 wechat.Dockerfile
```

2.Build docker image with commands:

```
 docker build -f  "wechat.Dockerfile"  --tag=wechat:0.0.1
```

Info:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
debian@debian:/tmp$  docker build -f  wechat.Dockerfile  --tag=wechat:0.0.1
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

Add `.` at the end of command:

```
docker build -f wechat.Dockerfile --tag=wechat:0.0.1 .
error checking context: 'can't stat '/tmp/systemd-private-ad10f6d540654f2791399efb421b6134-ModemManager.service-V2Upfj''.
```

No image 'wechat:0.0.1' created in current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command given is actually

```
docker build -f wechat.Dockerfile --tag=wechat:0.0.1 .
```

The final period is important, and denotes the current directory.

Comment: error checking context: 'can't stat '/tmp/systemd-private-ad10f6d540654f2791399efb421b6134-ModemManager.service-V2Upfj''.

Comment: Yes, the final period is the “context” and is required when building images. More info can be found in the documentation for docker build: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#usage.

Comment: When you add `.` to the end of the command, it’s essentially passing in the contents of that directory into the build process. Try putting the dockerfile into an empty directory and then running the command.